# spring boot mybatis field unique

Tags: spring, mybatis

## Hi,everyone:

I have a problem.
I have a model class  named User.The user have a unique field such as email.
So how can I tell the database this is a unique field.Is there any annotation such as @unique?

### Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
@Column(unique=true)
String email;
```

Comment: I use spring boot and ibatis .What maven dependency should I add?Please

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ibatis/ibatis-sqlmap -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.726</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(unique=true)
String email;
```

unique in @Column is used only if you let your JPA provider create the database for you (will be used only in DDL generation) - it will create the unique constraint on the specified column. But if you already have the database, or you alter it once created, then unique doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use @olumn annotation on email.

```
@Column(unique=true)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try.

Comment: I use spring boot.What maven dependency should I add?Please.

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Firstly,thanks very much.I use ibatis .But  I see the dependency is hibernate.